# Trying to make a points system with zelle graphics buttons

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I'm trying to make a game in python using the [Zelle graphics](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/) module for a project. (It has to be Zelle graphics). The program draws a random number of faces, and I have drawn buttons with text on them. I'm a complete beginner, and I apologize if this is really obvious.

I want the user to be able to select a button and have the button be their answer, but I can't quite figure out how to associate the button with a number, and then have that number be the correct answer which assigns points. There is no error, but the buttons don't work as intended. How can I make the button associated with a number answer?

```
def isBetween(x, end1, end2):
    return end1 <= x <= end2 or end2 <= x <= end1

def isInside(point, rect):
    pt1 = rect.getP1()
    pt2 = rect.getP2()
    return isBetween(point.getX(), pt1.getX(), pt2.getX()) and \
        isBetween(point.getY(), pt1.getY(), pt2.getY())

def makeColoredRect(corner, width, height, color, win):
    corner2 = corner.clone()  
    corner2.move(width, -height)
    rect = Rectangle(corner, corner2)
    rect.setFill(color)
    rect.draw(win)
    return rect

def getChoice(choicePairs, default, win):
    point = win.getMouse()
    for (rectangle, choice) in choicePairs:
        if isInside(point, rectangle):
            return choice
    return default

def makeButtonSetup(colors):
    buttons = list()
    x = 810
    y = 350
    for color in colors:
        buttons.append((x, y, color))
        y = y - 40
    return buttons

choicePairs = list()
buttonSetup = makeButtonSetup(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'orange', 'yellow'])
for (x, y, color) in buttonSetup:
    button = makeColoredRect(Point(x, y), 80, 30, color, win)
    choicePairs.append((button, color))

answerPairs = [(1, 'red'), (2, 'green'), (3, 'blue'), (4, 'purple'), (5, 'orange'), (6, 'yellow')]

redText = Text(Point(850, 335), "One Face")
redText.setSize(10)
redText.draw(win)
greenText = Text(Point(850, 295), "Two Faces")
greenText.setSize(10)
greenText.draw(win)
blueText = Text(Point(850, 255), "Three Faces")
blueText.setSize(10)
blueText.draw(win)
purpleText = Text(Point(850, 215), "Four Faces")
purpleText.setSize(10)
purpleText.draw(win)
orangeText = Text(Point(850, 175), "Five Faces")
orangeText.setSize(10)
orangeText.draw(win)
yellowText = Text(Point(850, 135), "Six Faces")
yellowText.setSize(10)
yellowText.draw(win)

numFaces = randint(1, 6)
print(numFaces)

points = 0
correctAnswer = True
def correct(points):    
    if correctAnswer == True:
        points = points+10
    print(points)
    if numFaces == 1:
        1 == True
    if numFaces == 2:
        2 == True       
    if numFaces == 3:
        3 == True
    if numFaces == 4:
        4 == True
    if numFaces == 5:
        5 == True
    if numFaces == 6:
        6 == True
    else:
        correctAnswer == False

def incorrectAnswer(points):
    correctAnswer = False
    if correctAnswer == False:
        points = 0
    print(points)

correct(points)

robots = []
for n in range(numFaces):
    robots.append(makeRobotFace())

i = 0
for robotList in robots:
    for robotPart in robotList:
        robotPart.draw(win)
        robotPart.move(i * 100, 0)
    i = i + 1

time.sleep(5)
i = 0

for robotList in robots:
    for robotPart in robotList:
        robotPart.undraw()
    i = i + 1

shapePairs = [(1, 'redText'), (2, 'greenText'), (3, 'blueText'), (4, 'purpleText'), (5, 'orangeText'), (6, 'yellowText')] 
msg = Text(Point(700, 400),'')
msg.draw(win)
for (shape, description) in shapePairs:
    time.sleep(.2)
    prompt = 'Click to choose an answer'
    msg.setText(prompt)
    answer = getChoice(choicePairs, shapePairs, win)
```

Comment: in `choicePairs` you should keep other informations - ie. `(button, color, number, answer)` so you don't have to search answer. Or at least use `(button, color, number)` and create dictionary `answerPairs = {1: 'red', 2:'green', ..}` or list `answerPairs = [ 'red', 'green', ...]` ,so you can get number from `button` and use it to get answer `answerPairs[number]`

Comment: BTW: you can always use `print()` to display values in variables and which part of code is executed (ie. `print("I'm in getChoice")`, `print( isInside(point, rectangle) )` ) and you will see if program has correct values in variables and if it execute code in correct order. It is called `"print debugging"`.

Comment: So to be clear you are saying it should be corrected to this:

`choicePairs = list(button, color, number, answer)`
    `buttonSetup = makeButtonSetup(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'orange', 'yellow'])`
    for (x, y, color) in buttonSetup:
        `button = makeColoredRect(Point(x, y), 80, 30, color, win)`
       `choicePairs.append((button, color))`

    `answerPairs = {1: 'red'}, {2: 'green'}, {3: 'blue'}, {4: 'purple'}, {5: 'orange'}, {6: 'yellow'}`

Comment: I can't run code to say somthing more but I would keep all in one place like `choicePairs = list(  (button1, color1, number1, answer1), (button2, color2, number2, answer2), ... )`. As for dictionary `answerPairs = {1: 'red', 2: 'green', 3: 'blue', 4: 'purple', 5: 'orange', 6: 'yellow'}` without `},{` inside.

Comment: Okay, I apologize but I'm not sure I understand.
I changed it to 
`choicePairs = list((button1, color1, number1, answer1), (button2, color2, number2, answer2), (button3, color3, number3, answer3) \
                      (button4, color4, number4, answer4), (button5, color5, number5, answer5), (button6, color6, number6, answer6))`

but I get the error that button1 is not defined.

Comment: `button1` is only information that you have to put differen value then in `button2` and `button3`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I cut off some part of code and create working example

```
from graphics import *
from random import randint
import graphics

# --- functions ---

def makeColoredRect(corner, width, height, color, win):
    corner2 = corner.clone()
    corner2.move(width, -height)

    rect = Rectangle(corner, corner2)
    rect.setFill(color)
    rect.draw(win)

    return rect

def makeText(text_position, text_string, win):
    text = Text(text_position, text_string)
    text.setSize(10)
    text.draw(win)

    return text

def makeButtons(buttonsSetup, win):
    buttons = list()

    x = 810
    y = 350

    for answer, color, text_string in buttonsSetup:
        # create button - rect & text
        rect = makeColoredRect(Point(x, y), 80, 30, color, win)

        text = makeText(Point(x+40, y-15), text_string, win)

        buttons.append( (answer, rect, text) )

        y = y - 40

    return buttons

def isBetween(x, end1, end2):
    return end1 <= x <= end2 or end2 <= x <= end1

def isInside(point, rect):
    pt1 = rect.getP1()
    pt2 = rect.getP2()
    return isBetween(point.getX(), pt1.getX(), pt2.getX()) and \
        isBetween(point.getY(), pt1.getY(), pt2.getY())

def getChoice(buttons, default, win):
    point = win.getMouse()

    for answer, rect, text in buttons:
        if isInside(point, rect):
            print('selected:', answer, text.getText())
            return answer

    return default

def checkAnswer(numFaces, answer, points):    
    print('points before:', points)

    if numFaces == answer:
        correctAnswer = True
        points = points + 10
    else:
        correctAnswer = False
        points = points - 10

    print('correct answer:', correctAnswer)
    print('points after:', points)

    return points, correctAnswer

# --- main ------------------------------------------------

points = 0
correctAnswer = None

buttonsSetup = [
#   (answer,  color,    text_string)
    (1,      'red',    "One Face"),
    (2,      'green',  "Two Faces"),
    (3,      'blue',   "Three Faces"),
    (4,      'purple', "Four Faces"),
    (5,      'orange', "Five Faces"),
    (6,      'yellow', "Six Faces"),
    ('exit', 'white',  "EXIT"),
]

# - start -

win = graphics.GraphWin(width=1000, height=600)

# - objects -

# it create list with elements `(answer, rect, text)`
buttons = makeButtons(buttonsSetup, win)

# select new number of faces

numFaces = randint(1, 6)
print('----')
print('numFaces:', numFaces)

# - mainloop -

while True:

    print('----')

    # check which button was clicked
    answer = getChoice(buttons, '', win)

    # exit `while` loop
    if answer == 'exit':
        break

    if answer != '':
        # compare selected answer with correct answer and change points
        points, correctAnswer = checkAnswer(numFaces, answer, points)

        if correctAnswer:
            # select new number of faces
            numFaces = randint(1, 6)
            print('----')
            print('numFaces:', numFaces)

# - exit -

win.close()
```